# stop chrome to show dropdown list when click a select

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to click a `<select>` but stop it to show his dropdown list

```
$('select').click(function(){
    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 20) {
        // some code to do my job
        return false;
    }
});
```

The code `return false` can stop dropdown list display in Firefox(actually, the dropdown list display first and hide after a short while), but not work in Chrome.

I also tried let the `<select>` to be disabled, trigger `blur()` on it, or trigger `click()` on other element, but the dropdown list is still there unless user click somewhere else.

Is this possible? ... and Thanks!

---

Long story is here (if you have interested in why I want to do that):

> As you know, sometimes there will be a `<select>` with too many
>   `<option>` in it, and when you click it, there will be a long dropdown
>   list. Find what you need in a long dropdown list is a terrible job...
>   But unfortunately there is a lot in my site.
>
> So I think the simplest way is to write some javascript to change
>   that, when option is more than 20, show a dialog with a filter and a
>   new `<select>` which only have filtered `<option>` to let find easy.
>
> And my problem is the dropdown list is still display, make my users
>   confused... They don't know where to operate. "the dialog or the
>   origin select".

Comment: Have you tried `.mousedown` and set it as disabled or returning the function false? I think this does not work because you are using the `.click`-event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the default action of a `select` element occurs on the `mousedown` event, rather than `click` (or `mouseup`), so you'll need to bind an event handler to `mousedown` instead:

```
$("select").mousedown(function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('option').length > 20) {
        e.preventDefault(); //return false will also work
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrg4R/1/). Note that I've used the [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method of the event object, simply because I think that makes it clearer what's actually happening. However, `return false` will work too.

Comment: `mousedown` works well in Chrome, but seems not work in Firefox, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable all form controls (with the 'form_control' class) in a table (id 'details_table'), including selects, and point users to an 'edit' button that opens a modal. A small tweak to the previous answers seemed to work in both Firefox and Chrome on Linux. Not tested in other browsers yet.

```
$('#details_table').on('mousedown', '.form-control', function(e) {
    alert("Please click on the Edit button to modify details.");
    e.preventDefault();
    this.blur();
});
```