# How can I prevent the dropdown from opening in a DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have a custom table which I'd like to use as the DropDown portion as a `DropDownList`.

[image: Table]

Ideally, when users click on a `DropDownList`, it should show the custom table instead of the usual drop down. I thought it'd be easy to prevent the dropdown from opening without disabling the DropDownList control, however that doesn't appear to be the case.

Is there an easy way to prevent a `DropDownList` from opening without disabling it?

**Edit:** This has to work for an embedded IE 7 web browser, and `e.preventDefault()` does not work in that browser version

Comment: If you are customizing the format of the dropdown contents, you might as well customize the dropdown itself as well.  Just use a textbox to display the current selected item, and a button with a down-arrow icon in it to resemble a dropdown.

Comment: @mellamokb I was hoping there'd be an easier way... I need to also track the `SelectedValue` and `DisplayValue` separately, since the actual selected value is the UTC date, while the display date is based on the user's timezone

Comment: Have you tried an `onclick` event with `preventDefault` or `return false`?

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, neither of those prevents the dropdown from opening. I tried both `click` and `mousedown`

Comment: `event.preventDefault` works for me on `mousedown` in Chrome at least: http://jsfiddle.net/RCCKj/.  Found on this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062138/stop-chrome-to-show-dropdown-list-when-click-a-select

Comment: @mellamokb It partially works for me... double-clicking still opens the dropdown. I must have had a syntax error the first time I tried and not noticed >.<

Comment: @Rachel: I'm not able to reproduce opening it with double-click.  What version of which browser are you using?  I clicked as fast as I possibly could (and that's pretty fast) and still the dropdown didn't open on the newest version of Chrome (19.0.1084.52).  However, I still stand by the cleanest method and most likely to be cross browser will be my first suggestion.  You might research if there exist any custom 3rd party controls that abstract a custom dropdown i.e., provide the same interface of `SelectedValue` and `DisplayValue` but allow overriding the display.

Comment: @mellamokb Perhaps it's just me... I'm using IE9 for testing. If I can't get it working I will probably end up using your solution of a simple TextBox & hidden label. You should post that as an answer, along with `preventdefault`. I'm fairly sure my solution will be one of those two depending on if I can get `preventdefault` working or not

Comment: @mellamokb It does work fine in Chrome for me though, so I guess it's an IE-only issue. Figures.

Comment: @mellamokb `preventdefault` actually does work for me correctly. For some reason I had to clear my IE temp files to get it to work correctly, but it works :) If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Basically, I have positioned an invisible div over the dropdown to block it, and you can handle the click with the onclick of the masking div.

EDIT: I have updated this http://jsfiddle.net/EdM7B/1/

```
<div id='mask' onclick='alert("clicked");' style='width:200px; height:20px; position:absolute; background:white;filter:alpha(opacity=0);'></div>
<select id='selectList' show=1 style='width:200px; height:20px;'>
    <option>Test</option>
</select>
```

I had to use a sort of hack because IE doesn't seem to render divs properly that have no background colour set, so it wasn't working correctly. This works in my IE7.

If you want it to work in all browsers you'll need to add chrome/firefox opacity CSS or have some IE only CSS to apply background colour.

I think due to the way it's positioned above, the opacity is actually not working properly because the element is positioned absolutely, either way it seems to work. I originally had it as opacity 1, but that sounds wrong to me as we want it invisible, so I changed it to 0.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to stop the dropdownlist from showing by using jQuery's `event.preventDefault` in the `mousedown` event (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RCCKj).

Also see this related question: [stop chrome to show dropdown list when click a select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062138/stop-chrome-to-show-dropdown-list-when-click-a-select)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this to work in an embedded IE 7 web browser and it doesn't.

Comment: On IE7, the "event.preventDefault()" command will throw a javascript error, probably because, in your case, "event" property refers to another event besides select's mousedown. But thanks to this javascript error, dropdown opening is prevented. A good "side-effect" maybe.

Comment: Was going to use this but it seems that if you double-click it in none debug mode (using ie10 emulating ie8) than it will open up the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2):

Put it inside a div like this:

```
    <div id="dllDiv" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
        < asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="z-index:-1000px;pointer-events:none;">
        < /asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```

You should set the css property pointer-events to none, then you can show your table hidden in a div or loaded it by using ajax, something like this:

```
   (document).ready(function() {
        $("#dllDiv").click(function() {
            alert('adasd');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a [mega menu](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) for this, you can put anything you want in the dropped down portion - for example your table